# Detect link click event in chat window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture the event that occurs when a user clicks a link on my chat application. I am using IE11.

Is there a way to capture the user clicking the link, when such a link could be dynamically added to the chat box (i.e. user sends "www.google.com" message) at any given time?

I have been using onbeforeunload by the way and while this detects the browser close event it will not detect the link click event, I am not sure why, so I was thinking that a jquery solution that checks the  links on the page for an onclick could solve my problem...

Thanks,
dearg

Comment: did you try to detect the click event like $('.chat-window a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) like:

```
$("#chatWindow).on('click', 'a', function () {
     //do something 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a function like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    //track clicked link here
    return true; //to allow following the link this is the default behavior no need to add

    return false; //prevent default behavior
});
```

Comment: Isnt this going to bind the event only to the *existing* links? he said that some links will come later from user input..

Comment: that's true if he doesn't execute that line with every refresh of the chat window.

Comment: I doubt that he would.

Comment: thanks to you, he's now aware that he has to do that - that's why I upvote your answer :)